# Server Requirements for SFS2X

Tags: smartfoxserver

I am developing a game which would be played by 1000 - 10000 users. Can SFS2X handle this range of users? If yes, what would be the server requirements, like OS, Hardware, RAM, HDD etc?

Your input would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes SFS can support 10,000 plus users.

The Free Version of SFS Server will support 100 users.But You have to purchase for your higher user needs.There are subscription details in the official website

> [Products Details](http://smartfoxserver.com/products)

Answer (score 0):

Server requirements just depends on your code on server , calculate the ram uses for one user then multiple it by 10000 , the CPU is same too , i mean , the requirements of server just depends on what u write and what server do for every user.
If your game just save some variables for every one , then you don't need very high ram for that , CPU is same too.